# Windows phone 7.1 set up

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a funny problem. I have to compile C, C++ code and then used the libraries in C# source code, on my visual studio 2013 professional.

I installed  visual studio 2013 professional and i am not able to create a windows phone 7.1 project. Just don't have option to choose the project type (windows phone)

Any helps, about setting up a windows phone project ?

I am on windows 7.

Comment: You can develop applications on Windows Phone 8 and later (OS 8) on VS 2013. VS 2013 does not support development of windows phone 7 apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support development for Windows Phone 7.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20395122/1803777)

Comment: i have windows 7, what could i do now ?even on visual studio 2012, windows phone 7.1 is not working

Comment: @NouridineBoukari For WP7 development in VS2012 you need to install [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 7 and you want to develop for Windows Phone 7, you have to use Visual Studio 2010. There is a free express edition just for Windows Phone available.

http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs